# How can I give my machine a static IP on LAN?

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, lan, static-ip

Today, when the power went of in the office, I got a new IP for my machine (I had 192.168.0.5 and got 192.168.0.6 when the power came back.)

That caused a problem because all the machines in the office are using my IP address to connect to the version control system installed on my Mac!

Please advise on how can I make the IP always the same. I'm using a D-link router.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- Assign an IP address in `System Preferences`, `Network` manually by selecting `Manually` for `Configure IPv4`
- Assuming the router is your DHCP server, open its web interface and search for the DHCP configuration. It might have an option to assign a permanent IP address for a specific machine or MAC address. Consult the router's manual for details.

The first option might lead to conflicts. It is generally a good idea to separate the range of addresses you assign manually from the range used by the DHCP server (e.g. x.x.x.1-x.x.x.100 manually, x.x.x.101-x.x.x.250 reserved for DHCP). In that case, you would need to reconfigure your other machines, something which could have been prevented with a bit of planning -- but you only need to do it once.

Comment: ...very much favouring the 2nd option over the first! (Just to avoid problems when some other computer is started before the Mac is, though a SVN server probably running 24/7?) A 3rd option: assign it a DNS name in the router's DHCP settings, so folks can use the name rather than some IP address.

Comment: @Arjan That's why I added the last paragraph. Don't know why it doesn't show up as being edited though.

Comment: you must have been typing that while I commented; your answer was not 5 minutes old yet, and edits within 5 minutes after the last edit do not count as separate edits (the [so-called "grace period"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted). Useful, but also abused a lot for the [Fasted Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)...)

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for the info on the grace period, although I don't think the osx tag and related tags are currently prone to this issue. Congrats on the 10k rep!